# What is the correct way to assign a value to a variable that will later be used in different script calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Having the following code

connection.js

```
import pkg from "pg";
const { Client } = pkg;

let connection = undefined;

export async function connect() {
    const client = new Client({
        user: "postgres",
        host: "localhost",
        database: "dbname",
        password: "password",
        port: "5432",
    });

    connection = await client.connect();
}

export async function query(text, values) {
    try {
        await connection.query(text, values);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
}
```

I intend that when calling the `connect` function a value is assigned to the `connection` variable that will then be used in the `query` function

This is how I call the connect method

index.js

```
import { connect } from "./src/connection.js";
import { handleStep1 } from "./src/step1.js";

async function init() {
    await connect();

    await handleStep1();
}

init();
```

And I intend to call the query function from another file as follows

step1.js

```
import { query } from "./connection.js";

export async function handleStep1() {
    const results = await query("SELECT * FROM public.user", []);

    console.log(results);
}
```

But here when calling the query function it gives me the following error message `Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`

What is the correct way to assign a value to a variable that will later be used in different script calls?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can also just connect() at the end of the file which will initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply export a variable which is intialized and import it anywhere you want.

```js
export async function connect() {
    const client = new Client({
        user: "postgres",
        host: "localhost",
        database: "dbname",
        password: "password",
        port: "5432",
    });

    connection = await client.connect();
}

export async function query(text, values) {
    try {
        await connection.query(text, values);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
    }
}

// export let connection = connect();
// import it in other files. like import{ connection } from from "./connection.js";

//if you need to all connect only once. just update the line to
let connection = connect(); //remove the connection imports in other files.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I intend to call connect only once, this from the initial script so that calls to query in other scripts use the same value assigned to connection

Comment: As per the above  code it will be called only once. you could add a console.log in connect function and verify it. for your information, you do not have to export the connection as per your code flow. because only query needs to be imported in other places and called.